# Which one is initialized, property or its instance variable

Tags: objective-c, properties, ivar

Suppose I have a property called `myPropertyName` defined in my class `MyClassName`. Manual memory management is used throughout this post.

**MyClassName.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MyClassName : NSObject {
    @private
        NSObject* myPropertyName;
    @public
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSObject* myPropertyName;
// Some methods prototypes are here
@end
```

**MyClassName.m**

```
#import "MyClassName.h"
@implementation MyClassName
@synthesize myPropertyName;
// Some methods are here
@end
```

I'm confused with usages such as the place of `myPropertyName` declaration, its difference between instance variable. For example, what is the difference among these three statement of initialization code, for example, in the customized `-(void)init` method for my class `myClassName`.

1. `self.myPropertyName = [[[NSObject alloc] init] autorelease];`

   This one is calling `myPropertyName` setter, but I'm not sure what is the name of the instance variable being used in the setter, `myPropertyName` (since I've declared a @private field named `myPropertyName`) or `_myPropertyName` (people say that this one with underbar is the default)?
2. `myPropertyName = [[NSObject alloc] init];`

   Does this initialize the instance variable of the `myPropertyName` property? If I don't have `@synthesize myPropertyName = _myPropertyName;`, would it be wrong since the default instance variable for the property is said to be `_myPropertyName`.
3. `_myPropertyName = [[NSObject alloc] init];`

   Is `_myPropertyName` still declared as the instance variable for my property `myPropertyName` even if I use `@synthesize myPropertyName;` and `@private NSObject* myPropertyName;`?

In my understanding, a property is just a name (such as `myPropertyName`), there should be some instance variable encapsulated to be used in actual operations in the code, such as assigning values.

Comment: You don't have to `@synthesize` any more.  In regards to what seems to be your actual question, you can have a `@property` without a corresponding `ivar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I highly recommend reading [Apple's documentation on properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html), also linked by nhgrif.  However, I understand docs can be a bit dense reading material (though Apple's, I find, are not so bad), so I'll give a brief overview of properties here.

I like examples, so I'm going to rewrite your two classes in a bit more current form.

**MyClassName.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MyClassName : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSObject *myPropertyName;
// method prototypes here
@end
```

**MyClassName.m**

```
#import "MyClassName.h"
@implementation MyClassName
// some methods here
@end
```

The class `MyClassName` now has a property called `myPropertyName` of type `NSObject *`.  The compiler will do a lot of work for you for "free" in this instance.  Specifically, it will generate a backing variable, and also generate a setter and getter for `myPropertyName`.  If I were to rewrite the two files, and pretend I'm the compiler, including that stuff, they would look like this:

**MyClassName.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MyClassName : NSObject {
    NSObject *_myPropertyName;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSObject *myPropertyName;

- (void)setMyPropertyName:(NSObject *)obj;
- (NSObject *)myPropertyName;

@end
```

**MyClassName.m**

```
#import "MyClassName.h"
@implementation MyClassName

- (void)setMyPropertyName:(NSObject *)obj
{
    _myPropertyName = obj;
}

- (NSObject *)myPropertyName
{
    return _myPropertyName;
}

@end
```

Again, all of this is happening for "free": I'm just showing you what's happening under the hood.  Now for your numbered questions.

1. `self.myPropertyName = [[[NSObject alloc] init] autorelease];`

   First of all, you should probably be using Automatic Reference Counting, or ARC.  If you are, you won't be allowed to call `autorelease`.  Ignoring that part, this works fine.  Excluding the `autorelease`, this is exactly equivalent to:

   [self setMyPropertyName:[[NSObject alloc] init]];

   Which, if you look at the second `.m` file I wrote out, above, will basically translate to:

   `_myPropertyName = [[NSObject alloc] init];
2. `myPropertyName = [[NSObject alloc] init];`

   As written, this code will give a compiler error, since there is no variable called `myPropertyName` in this class.  If you really want to access the instance variable underlying (or, "backing") the `myPropertyName` property, you can, by using its real name:

   `_myPropertyName = [[NSObject alloc] init];   // note the underscore`

   But most of the time, it's better to use the setter, as in point 1., since that allows for side effects, and for Key-Value Coding, and other good stuff.
3. `_myPropertyName = [[NSObject alloc] init];`

   Oh.  Well you got it.  See point 2.

You mentioned that:

> I'm confused with usages such as the place of `myPropertyName` declaration, its difference between instance variable. For example, what is the difference among these three statement of initialization code, for example, in the customized `-(void)init` method for my class `myClassName`.

In case it hasn't been made clear, a property is something of an abstract concept; its data is stored in a normal instance variable, typically assigned by the compiler.  Its access should usually be restricted to the setter and getter, with important exceptions.  To keep this answer short, I won't go into more detail than that.

One more thing: as nhgrif mentioned, you don't need to use the `@synthesize` keyword anymore.  That is implicitly understood by the compiler now.

If you're not sure about any of this, post a comment or, better yet, read the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html).

Comment: To @Riley, in your this sentence *"As written, this code will give a compiler error, since there is no variable called _myPropertyName in this class. If you really want to access the instance variable underlying (or, "backing") the myPropertyName property, you can, by using its real name."* Do you in fact mean "there is no variable called **`myPropertyName`** in this class"?

Comment: @conglu I did indeed.  Thanks very much for pointing that out.  My answer has been edited.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take this example:

```
@property NSString *fullName;
```

If in the implementation, we override the setters and getters, and in these setters and getters, we don't use an instance variable `fullName`, it is never created.  For example:

```
- (NSString *)fullName
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.firstName, self.lastName];
}

- (void)setFullName:(NSString *)fullName
{
    //logic to split fullName into two strings
    //self.firstName = etc
    //self.lastName = etc.
}
```

In this example, there is no instance variable for `fullName` created.

This is according to [Apple's Official Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html)

If, however, you don't override both the setter and getter, an instance variable is created.

As a sidenote, you can declare a property `readonly`, and then simply overriding the `getter` (without using the variable) will prevent an `ivar` being created.  Likewise, you can declare a property `writeonly` and just override the `setter`.